# HTML5: Make page load external url in right iframe when using a sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this code from ChatGPT to create a dynamic sidebar and load urls in the right panel when clicking an entry:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HTML5 Sidebar with Secure Content-Security-Policy</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #container {
      display: flex;
    }

    #sidebar {
      width: 250px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    #content {
      flex: 1;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    /* Style for the sidebar entries */
    .sidebar-entry {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: #ddd;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* Style for active sidebar entry */
    .sidebar-entry.active {
      background-color: #007bff;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https:;">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar Entries -->
      <div class="sidebar-entry" data-url="https://mysite.domain.com">
        Entry 1
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-entry" data-url="https://mysite2.mydomain.com">
        Entry 2
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-entry" data-url="https://www.example.net">
        Entry 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <iframe id="iframe-content" src="" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Get the sidebar entries and the iframe content
    const sidebarEntries = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-entry');
    const iframeContent = document.getElementById('iframe-content');

    // Function to load content in the iframe
    function loadContent(url) {
      iframeContent.src = url;
    }

    // Event listener for clicking on sidebar entries
    sidebarEntries.forEach(entry => {
      entry.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Remove the 'active' class from all entries
        sidebarEntries.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
        
        // Add the 'active' class to the clicked entry
        this.classList.add('active');

        // Load the content in the iframe
        loadContent(this.getAttribute('data-url'));
      });
    });

    // Load the first entry by default
    if (sidebarEntries.length > 0) {
      sidebarEntries[0].click();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but the browser refuses to load the content of mysite.domain.com in the right panel.

Any ideas how I could tell the browser to load the content?

I have tried different Content-Security-Policy but no success.

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it includes content written by a chatbot (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned )

Comment: (It’s also taking a really awful approach to solving the initial problem)

Comment: Also “refuses to load the content” is a really unhelpful description of the problem. If it is refusing to do so then it will be outputting an error message which should be quoted in full.

Comment: @Quentin I interpret the policy as banning the use of chatbots to generate a question or answer, whereas this question is seeking help implementing the results.

Comment: @TimR — from the link "This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output"  which this clearly is.

Comment: Whether the code works depends on the URLs used. I'm guessing it doesn't work if the website blocks being loaded inside of an iframe.

Comment: @TimR yes, I understood that. The URLs have the same domain name as the site with code above, but Chrome and Firefox refuse to load them. I guess it has to do with cross site scripting, but I don't know how to allow those certain URLs.

Answer (score -1):

It works now.
The application loading in an iframe actually set a x-frame-options header to deny, which made the browser not load the target url. Closing this.